# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I want to add a new site in wordpress when i log in to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/network/index.php` it showed me this error.

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I'm new in wordpress plz guide me how to add new site ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to WP config files. Trw to chmod 777  /wp-admin/*.php, make sure that you are the file's owner.

Check this out for more infos : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-blogwp-adminoptionsphp